# CSS3 loop animation with <ul>

Tags: css, animation, keyframe

I'm trying to use this code for a website.
I'm using CSS3 Keyframe and animations for it with a simple  list

```css
#animation ul { /* The list with elements */
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
}
#animation li { /* Common styles for the list elements */
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}
#animation li:nth-of-type(1) { /* First element of the list */
    background-color: lightgreen;
    
    -webkit-animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out -4s infinite alternate; /* delay = -duration * 66%. Note the negative delay to skip the "keyframes delay" */
    -moz-animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out -4s infinite alternate;
    animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out -4s infinite alternate;
}
#animation li:nth-of-type(2) { /* Second element of the list */
    background-color: yellow;
    
    -webkit-animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate; 
    -moz-animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
    animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
}
#animation li:nth-of-type(3) { /* Third element of the list */
    background-color: lightblue;
    
    -webkit-animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out 4s infinite alternate; /* delay = duration * 66% */
    -moz-animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out 4s infinite alternate;
    animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out 4s infinite alternate;
}


/* Defines the animation keyframes */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    0% {           /* "Delay" of the animation - 66% of the duration time (100 - 100/number of elements) */ 
        opacity: 0;
    }
    66% {          /* Actual beginning of the fade in animation */
        opacity: 0;
    }
    76% {          /* The fade in animation takes 10% of the duration time */
        opacity: 1;
    }    
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }    
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    66% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    76% {
        opacity: 1;
    }    
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }    
}
@keyframes fadein {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    66% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    76% {
        opacity: 1;
    }    
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }    
}
```

```html
<div id="animation">
    <ul>
        <li>This is</li>
        <li>CSS3 looped</li>
        <li>animation</li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to set 5 elements instead of 3 but when I edit this code with 5 elements, it's not the same result..

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the time intervels that you have mentioned . Check the below code.

```css
#animation ul { /* The list with elements */
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 200px;
}
#animation li { /* Common styles for the list elements */
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}
#animation li:nth-of-type(1) { /* First element of the list */
    background-color: lightgreen;
    
    -webkit-animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out -4s infinite alternate; /* delay = -duration * 66%. Note the negative delay to skip the "keyframes delay" */
    -moz-animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out -4s infinite alternate;
    animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out -4s infinite alternate;
}
#animation li:nth-of-type(2) { /* Second element of the list */
    background-color: yellow;
    
    -webkit-animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate; 
    -moz-animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
    animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate;
}
#animation li:nth-of-type(3) { /* Third element of the list */
    background-color: lightblue;
    
    -webkit-animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out 4s infinite alternate; /* delay = duration * 66% */
    -moz-animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out 4s infinite alternate;
    animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out 4s infinite alternate;
}
#animation li:nth-of-type(4) { /* fourth element of the list */
background-color: pink;

-webkit-animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out 8s infinite alternate; /* delay = duration * 66% */
-moz-animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out 8s infinite alternate;
animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out 8s infinite alternate;
}
#animation li:nth-of-type(5) { /* fifth element of the list */
background-color: red;

-webkit-animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out 12s infinite alternate; 
-moz-animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out 12s infinite alternate;
animation: fadein 6s ease-in-out 12s infinite alternate;
}


/* Defines the animation keyframes */
@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
    0% {           /* "Delay" of the animation - 66% of the duration time (100 - 100/number of elements) */ 
        opacity: 0;
    }
    66% {          /* Actual beginning of the fade in animation */
        opacity: 0;
    }
    76% {          /* The fade in animation takes 10% of the duration time */
        opacity: 1;
    }    
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }    
}
@-moz-keyframes fadein {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    66% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    76% {
        opacity: 1;
    }    
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }    
}
@keyframes fadein {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    66% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    76% {
        opacity: 1;
    }    
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }    
}
```

```html
<div id="animation">
    <ul>
        <li>This is</li>
        <li>CSS3 looped</li>
        <li>animation</li>
        <li>example</li>
        <li>here</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I did it but the problem is still here, look at the two last li, some text appear before it comes correctly over

Comment: Wait let me check it once.

Comment: I guess the text that appear before is because of the fade in intervals. Try changing them and check it out once.

Comment: You mean this ->  -webkit-animation: fadein 6s

Comment: yea. Just check it out that